# Calling JavaScript from code Behind in aspx

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have this javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll, pos) {
        var win = null;
        if (pos == "random") {
            LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (screen.width - w)) : 100;
            TopPosition = (screen.height) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * ((screen.height - h) - 75)) : 100;
        }
        if (pos == "center") {
            LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - w) / 2 : 100;
            TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - h) / 2 : 100;
        }
        else if ((pos != "center" && pos != "random") || pos == null) {
            LeftPosition = 0; TopPosition = 20
        }
        settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no';
        win = window.open(mypage, myname, settings);
    }
</script>
```

And I'm trying to call this function from my code behind as follows:

```
Dim Message As String = "This is My new Message"
Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
Dim script As String = "NewWindow(" & url & "," & Message & ",200,50,Yes,random)"
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "alertscript") Then
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", script, True)
        End If
```

The all idea is to have popup windows in case or error messages in my web site.
The vb code is taking all the attributes I want.
But the function in my aspx.page is not called.

Comment: Where in the code are you calling RegisterStartupScript from?

Comment: Are you using JQuery? If yes, maybe you can set with your code behind  "$(document).ready()" to run you alert calling after entire document is available. Try a simple alert first, and them in you function put a simple alert and call the function to verify if it is firing.

Comment: @SystemDown the script I call it from my code behind and in the `Load` Event.

Comment: @AndrewPaes Please give more assistance on your suggestion because I'm not so familiar with script and asp net. This my first work.

Comment: Have you turned on the script console in your browser? A simple JavaScript error somewhere could be causing this.

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis OK. I will do that. I'm sorry.

Comment: You say the function is not called because it's not doing anything? Perhaps it is called and something is wrong with your JavaScript ? Have you tried adding "debugger;" at the top of your function and enabling JavaScript debugging in IE ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2h50zzs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Lefteri, actually you are not call the js from code behind, you only register some script to run, after your function declaration. If not working view what is rendered on page, and / or look for javascript errors.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme I try to do what instruct me to do but throw me an error `HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Call Failed of LoadLibraryEx in Filter ISAPI "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll"`. And that is when I was try to enable the debugger in ie 7.5 `c:\localhost\cookie.html`

Comment: @Aristos I did look with `Inspect Element` tool and I see that the script is `{ }`

Comment: Hmm, IE 7.5. That sounds old. Perhaps the interaction between the JavaScript in your browser and Visual Studio is screwy. Which version of VS are you using ? debugger; works fine for me. It's suppose to tell you an exception occured then offers you to debug. If you do so, VS opens the JavaScript and breaks at the line of code where you have written debugger;

Comment: @FrancisDucharme it the latest version Microsoft was send me... sorry sorry sorry ie 11 sorry my mistake

Comment: Well, that's getting tricky. On which version of Windows are you developing ? x86 or x64 ? The application itself, x86, x64 ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme Window is x64 and the application is x64 it is a new project I open it just to test this for. Basically I found the issue of `not calling the script` it was the quotes... I forgot to add the quotes on my call since I put then the script is run... BUT I'm facing a new issue now... the `window.open(mypage, myname, settings)` throw me an error `wrong arguments` and now I'm trying to figure something by Google. Since I can't find anything I open a new QUESTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one please:

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TesteVB._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome to ASP.NET!
    </h2>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function Test() {
            alert('Banzai');
        }

        function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll, pos) {
            var win = null;
            if (pos == "random") {
                LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * (screen.width - w)) : 100;
                TopPosition = (screen.height) ? Math.floor(Math.random() * ((screen.height - h) - 75)) : 100;
            }

            if (pos == "center") {
                LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - w) / 2 : 100;
                TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - h) / 2 : 100;
            }
            else if ((pos != "center" && pos != "random") || pos == null) {
                LeftPosition = 0; TopPosition = 20
            }

            settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no';

            win = window.open(mypage, myname, settings);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.vb

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim csname1 As String = "PopupScript"
        Dim csname2 As String = "AutoPopup"
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()

        ' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

        ' Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
        If (Not cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1)) Then

            'Dim cstext1 As String = "Test();"
            'cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1, True)

            Dim Message As String = "This is My new Message"
            Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
            Dim script As String = "NewWindow('" & url & "','" & Message & "',200,50,'Yes','random');"

            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, script, True)

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I did paste the code and the new script in the exact place I run it but I have the same result... Nothing... I have a secrete filling that the script never call it... for some reason...

Comment: I tested here and everything functioned normally with the same code. Pay attention that I put the quotation marks. I tested in Firefox with my debug on and gave no error. Uncomment the lines that makes the call the Test function and comment on others that are below and tell me what happened. Your Web browser is enabled to perform JS?

Comment: Yes by default it is the ie 11. I have Google as well... same issues

Comment: Do you have another JS script that might be giving error in your code?

Comment: No all the other scripts i was use are run just fine

Comment: I did made the changes you instruct me but nothing nothing change it

Comment: I really don't what could be worng. I started a new project and paste this code again and everything is fine. Sorry.

Comment: I will start a new project my self too and see what is going wrong Thanks allot for all of your efforts

Comment: Quotes Quotes Quots Quots Quots... that was the problem I discover it when I start a new project from scratch. Now I'm facing the issue of the `window.open(mypage, myname, settings);` parameters are wrong... soon I'll see what is going on with it I'll post the right answer for all of our friends.

Comment: I told you to pay attention to the quotes om my comments, second one. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to place "NewWindow where your script is.. like this..

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "NewWindow();", true);
```

This is how I call mine.

Edit: Try this. It's not tested.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "Call my function", "NewWindow();", True)
```

Comment: I think I've miss a `;` is that important?

Comment: What I have when I use the `Inspect Element` in my browser is `{
}` that is the script... completely empty from parameters...

Comment: Is it possible to run the script from inside of my code behind?  and if I can how can I do it?

Comment: Do you want to declare a JS function in the aspx page and then perform the function of the code behind?

No you can't do that. When you declare a JS function it will be a client side script and can only be performed by client events while/after the page is loaded. You can make a declaration of a JS function from code behind and call a JS function from the code behind, but it can only be executed from a client-side event.

Comment: @Humpy I did the changes and nothing happen